# Copy resource files from submodule into main module in maven

Tags: java, maven, resources

In my java application, I am just wondering if it is possible to copy or just use resource files from under src/main/resources from a maven submodule into a main maven module (which has the submodule as a dependency) src/main/resources folder, so I don't need to copy manually all the resource files again into my workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven dependency plugin to do that.

Here is a configuration that you can include in your main module pom.xml in the build > plugins section.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>hepl.cecotepe.epick</groupId>
                                <artifactId>wsdl</artifactId>
                                <version>${wsdl.version}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/webservices</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>**/*.wsdl, **/*.xsd</includes>
                        <excludes>**/META*/**, **/Documentation/**</excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The artifactItem is the module from which you want to copy the files into your module. In this case, you will fill the artifactItem fields with your submodule groupId, artifactId and version.

The plugin will take all .wsdl and .xsd files across all folders (including target, src and subfolders) except the Documentation and META* folders (and subfolders). The files will be copied each time in the main module /resources/webservices folder.

To make the whole thing work, you need to package the submodule as a jar (include jar in your submodule pom.xml) and install it in your local maven repository using **mvn install**. After, you can copy the files in the main module with **mvn initialize**

NOTE : The initialize phase is included in the default lifecycle and is the first phase executed. When you use the default lifecycle, the first thing maven will do will be to copy the files from the submodule to the main module.